# Jquery cookies issue with multiple buttonsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

As per this question I asked and answered myself...
[setting jquery cookies for buttonset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754634/setting-jquery-cookies-for-buttonset)
I'm able to set cookies for individual buttonsets but now I'm trying to do the same for multiple buttonsets. I got it to work only thing I can't figure out is how to select and refresh the buttonsets... which ironically was the the problem I was having with my first question but I figured out how to do it, no such luck this time.

```
$(function(){ 
  var radioButtonSet=$('.setCookies').find('.setupRadioButtons');
  radioButtonSet.buttonset();
  var radio=$('.setupRadioButtons').find(':radio'), radioCookieName='selection';

  radio.each(function(){
    var selected=$.cookie(radioCookieName + '|' + this.name);
    $(this).prop('checked', true).button('refresh')  // CAN'T GET THIS TO WORK
    $(this).click(function() {
      $.cookie(radioCookieName + '|' + this.name, $(this).val(), {expires: 365});    
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well once again I figured it out...

Here's the working code...

```
$(function(){                                                                                       // Sets cookies for Check boxes
    var radioButtonSet=$('.setCookies').find('.radioButtons');
    radioButtonSet.buttonset();
    var radio=$('.radioButtons').find(':radio');

    radio.each(function(){
        var selected=$.cookie(this.name);
        $('#'+selected).prop('checked', true).button('refresh');

        $(this).click(function() {
            $.cookie(this.name, this.id, {expires: 365});
        });
    });
});
```